# How to get a scenario context of an IList to display text?

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a method that stores a list of drop-down options into a list and then set it as a scenario context:

```
public void GetBookingContactOptions() {

   var bookingContactDropdown = _driver.FindElement(PaymentDetailsResponsiveElements.BookingContactDropdown);
   SelectElement bookingContacts = new SelectElement(bookingContactDropdown);
   IList<IWebElement> bookingContactOptions = bookingContacts.Options;
   ScenarioContext.Current.Add("BookingContactOptions", bookingContactOptions);

}
```

I want to perform an assertion to check that the drop down contains an option 'Someone else'.

```
[Then(@"the booking contact drop-down displays the correct passengers")]
public void ThenTheBookingContactDropDownDisplaysTheCorrectPassengers() {

        string bookingContactsList = ScenarioContext.Current["BookingContactOptions"].ToString();

        Assert.True(bookingContactsList.Contains("Someone else"),
                "Booking contact drop down does not contain the option 'Someone else'");

}
```

However, it keeps failing in the assertion and I believe it is because it is because of the output for 'bookingContactList'.

It outputs this:

```
"System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection`1[OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement]"
```

However, I want it to output the text of each option which should be:

```
Choose from List
Mr Test Tester
Miss Testing Tester
Someone else
```

How can I have the text to be outputted of all the options so I can complete the assertion?

Thanks.

Comment: ``string.Join(Environment.NewLine, ((IList<IWebElement>)ScenarioContext.Current["BookingContactOptions"]).Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());`` - if IWebElements ``ToString()`` result in your desired output

Comment: I included the above you stated in the step definition but it states the given key is not recognised which is strange.

Comment: @RandRandom Your solution did work after slight amendment. Thanks

Comment: You can answer your own question for future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get value of the first option like this:

```
firstOption = bookingContactOptions[0]
firstOption.GetAttribute("value")
```

PS: You can get all options in the loop by using the index in the list.